# Import browser passwords from another profile in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, password-management

How do I import password sin Microsoft edge from one profile to another?

the import options in the Edge browser only show 3 options below ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL5gV.png)):

- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Internet Explorer
- Favorites or Bookmarks HTML

Edge does support exporting all the password into a CSV file. Is it possible to import them?

Comment: [Yes])https://www.groovypost.com/howto/export-passwords-from-microsoft-edge/); Microsoft Edge supports export your passwords to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can export and import passwords in Edge, like this :

- Open `edge://settings/passwords`
- Click the three-points icon to the right of "Add password"
- You will see this menu :

  [image]
- On the source profile, use "Export passwords", give your
  Windows password and export to a file
- On the target profile, use "Import passwords" and point to this file.

(Remember that your passwords in the file are visible and in plain text.)

Comment: If the option to import the password does not exist, make sure you are using the current version of Edge, and then launch Edge with the [--enable-features=msEdgePasswordImport](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftEdge/comments/nqt6zc/import_passwords_not_working/) option

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the "Import Password" feature doesn't support importing from file, nor does it support importing from another Microsoft Edge. I've included a screenshot for reference. Please add more details to your answer on "Import Password with file"